# How to vibrate an iPhone ad infinitum

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Wondering what code in objective-c should I use to shake the iPhone continuously...

Comment: This is naughty. +1 :)

Comment: +1 for doing something awful to iPhone users

Comment: awful? I imagine it could be quite pleasant...

Comment: This is very similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265761/how-do-you-make-the-iphone-vibrate-for-arbitrary-durations  Note that Apple will reject your application if you do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to use the code from "[How do you make the iPhone vibrate for arbitrary durations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265761/how-do-you-make-the-iphone-vibrate-for-arbitrary-durations)":

```
extern void * _CTServerConnectionCreate( CFAllocatorRef, int (*)(void *, CFStringRef, CFDictionaryRef, void *), int *);
extern int _CTServerConnectionSetVibratorState(int *, void *, int, int, float, float, float);

// Initialize
connection = _CTServerConnectionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, &vibratecallback, &x);

// Start Vibration
_CTServerConnectionSetVibratorState(&x, connection, 3, intensity, 0, 0, 0);

// End Vibration
_CTServerConnectionSetVibratorState(&x, connection, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

I bet this will make it quite difficult for your application to get approved for AppStore! Check out the [Unofficial App Store Rejection Criteria](http://10base-t.com/unofficial-appstore-rejection-criteria/).

Answer (score 0):

I disagree iOS 5 has implemented Custom Vibrations mode. So in some cases variable vibration is acceptable. The only thing is unknown what library deals with that (pretty sure not CoreTelephony.framework) and if it is open for developers.

Answer (score -3):

Don't do this.  Besides the fact it could get you rejected, it's simply bad form.