# iPhone vibrate for short time

Tags: iphone, ios5, short, vibration

I'm currently using the AudioServicesPlaySystemSound method.

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

But unfortunately for me the vibration is too long.
Anybody knows how to make this shorter?

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265761/how-do-you-make-the-iphone-vibrate-for-arbitrary-durations?rq=1

Comment: Thanks but as you can read, it is an unofficial way and the app might get rejected from the appStore.

Comment: Yup, that's correct. There's nothing on the linked question to suggest there's an official way to do this, sadly *shrug*

Comment: Then that does not solve my problem, thanks.

Comment: Have you found any solution??

Comment: No @MrugeshTank, I didn't at the time, but maybe now there is a solution.

Comment: @SergioM, What is it? Can you give some hint/tutorial link/code snippet?