# iOS custom vibrations

Tags: objective-c, ios5, vibration

I've made a custom vibration on my iPhone that I want to use in an app that I'm making. Now I've been able to extract the pattern from my phone, however it's a plist file. Does anyone know if there is a way to play this custom vibration in my app from the plist file?

Or if that's not possible: could I make a settings pane that allows people to connect any vibration to my app? Just like it can be done with contacts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there APIs for custom vibrations in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966467/are-there-apis-for-custom-vibrations-in-ios)

Comment: Similar indeed, but no reference to the use of the plist files that Apple uses for their custom vibrations. I was hoping those plists might help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so nowhere near as cool as a true custom vibration, and especially not as nice as just having that setting panel for custom vibrations in your app (would be awesome if we could just use that standard panel for vibration settings and let users customize the vibration to their own taste...)

But my solution, use a timer to fire the normal "kSystemSoundID_Vibrate" and play with the interval. Because you can only fire those one at a time, you can make shorter and softer vibrations by decreasing the time between calls. Not very pretty, but it does work...