# vibration in iphone

Tags: iphone, sdk, iphone-vibrate

Is there a way to reduce the vibration time in iphone when calling

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

At the time is 2 seconds and I need it to be 0.5 sec.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, custom vibration is not possible using the official SDK.

For iOS 6 private API, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13047464/983912

Comment: Apple's guidelines state that vibration should be used only as a mean to notify the user of an event, as means of accessibility. However, in iOS 6 (and possibly iOS 5), Apple's own "vibration designer" suggest Apple might be moving away from that. The private API linked above can be seen as a sign of things to come.

Comment: I'll wait for the "things to come". Don't wanna spend hours of coding for a feature that most likely reject my app. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is it still not possible to change vibration length?