# Producing Custom Vibration in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ipod, vibration

I have an app that makes Custom Vibrations. i.e. Changes the intensity and the duration. I came to know that this can be done using one of the private functions of AudioToolBox Framework. 
Function details:

```
void AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration(SystemSoundID inSystemSoundID,id arg,NSDictionary* vibratePattern)
```

The method on how to use the function is described in this post :
[Are there APIs for custom vibrations in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966467/are-there-apis-for-custom-vibrations-in-ios)

My question is :

As also said in one of the comments in above post, is this possible to use this function and get your app approved by Apple. Or there is certainty that this would be rejected by Apple?

Comment: I think this question is off-topic, as it is not directly questioning the coding of the app. Perhaps you might get a better response to your question on iOS forums?

Comment: Do you know of any other way in IOS that we can use to control the duration and intensity of the vibration through code?

Comment: Private API = rejection.  End of story.

Comment: @iOS: Names are not code.