# Intensity of custom iPhone vibration

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-privateapi, vibration, iphone-vibrate

This is a question related to [Are there APIs for custom vibrations in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966467/are-there-apis-for-custom-vibrations-in-ios). 
I am able to create custom vibration patterns, but have no control over the intensity.

This is copied over from Kevin Cao's answer that enables custom vibration patterns:

```
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSMutableArray* arr = [NSMutableArray array ];

[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]; //vibrate for 2000ms
[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2000]];

[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];  //stop for 1000ms
[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1000]];

[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];  //vibrate for 1000ms
[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1000]];

[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];    //stop for 500ms
[arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:500]];

[dict setObject:arr forKey:@"VibePattern"];
[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"Intensity"];


AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration(4095,nil,dict);
```

The line of code that adds the key `@"Intensity"` with an `int` value doesn't do the trick and I don't know how to look inside the `AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration` method to figure it out. What do I have to pass to it so that it actually changes the intensity?
Right now, it doesn't matter if I pass 1, 1000, 0.4 or 0.0001, it's always the same intensity (on an iPhone 4 with iOS7). **Can anyone recreate this?**

I would like to be able not only to create vibration patterns, but a smooth vibration envelope. **How to?**

---

*(As this is a research project for instrument design, I am not (yet) concerned with the App store restrictions.)*

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I suspect that the iPhone hardware simply doesn't support variable vibration intensity at this point. I've certainly never seen it use that capability, if it exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `numberWithInt` call into `numberWithFloat`, and change the intensity so it's between 0 and 1. I thought it was weird when they used an `int` rather than a `float`.

---

#### Edit: Here's a copy/paste that should work for your code to invoke custom vibration:

```
#pragma mark - Custom vibration methods
-(void)invokeCustomVibrationWithStartStopTimes:(NSArray*)startStopTimes andIntensity:(float)intensity {
    BOOL startOrStop = YES;
    NSMutableArray* arr = [@[] mutableCopy];
    double time = 0;
    for (NSNumber *x in stopStartTimes) {
        [arr addObject:x]
        startOrStop = !startOrStop;
        [arr addObject:@(startOrStop)];
        time = [x doubleValue] / 1000.0;
    }
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration(4095,nil,{@"VibePattern":arr,@"Intensity":@(intensity)})
    [self performSelector:@selector(stop) withObject:nil afterDelay:time];
}

-(void)stop {
    AudioServicesStopSystemSound(4095); // stop buzzing the phone
}
```

For `startStopTimes`, it should alternate between times started and times stopped. Passing in this array:

```
@[@(2000), @(1000), @(1000), @(500)]
```

Will do what the example code did. In this case, it will start for 2000 ms, stop for 1000 ms, start for 1000 ms, and stop for 500 ms.

`stop` is called to stop the sound. The way I have it set up, it stops sounds after the total amount of time sent in.

You may have noticed I've been using array/number literals rather than using `[NSArray arrayWithObjects: ... , nil];` or `[NSNumber numberWith...];`. This makes your code a lot shorter. Also, I marked the beginning with a `#pragma mark`. Use that to organize it better. Hope it helps!

Comment: `You may have noticed I've been using array/number literals`.. Is there any particular reason you favour `dictionaryWithObjects: forKeys:` over `@{}`

Comment: @JamesWebster I forgot how to use dictionary literals.

Comment: It's just `@{ key : value, key : value, ... }`

Comment: @DDPWNAGE I'm getting statement error like "implicit declaration of function AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration is invalid in C99". what is the alternate of this method. can you please help on this ? I need to run vibration about 500ms not more than this.

Comment: i guess it is the private API they are using..Is there any IOS api for changing the intensity of vibration and duration too

Comment: Shouldn't it be `time += [x doubleValue] / 1000.0;`?