# On IOS how to vibrate sweetly the phone?

Tags: ios, iphone

Actually to vibrate the iphone I do `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);` but it's a little too strong (or too long), I want something more sweet. How can I do it ?

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822295/intensity-of-custom-iphone-vibration

Comment: as far as i know we need to call AudioServicesStopSystemSound to stop the vibration, and this i quite problematic :(