# Can we create custom vibration in iPhone and search location of incoming call

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, iphone-vibrate, contact-list

I want to create an app that respond different on income call from contact list. I need to create custom vibration alert for different person. Can we detect incoming call location during its vibrating?

Comment: iOS already allows you to set different rings tones and vibrations per user in your contacts list. And on a non-jailbroken phone you can't even access the details of a call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot find the location of a call during vibration.. for custom vibration have a look at this.. [Are there APIs for custom vibrations in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966467/are-there-apis-for-custom-vibrations-in-ios) but beware your app might get rejected at appstore..

Answer (score 0):

You can detect incoming calls using the [`CoreTelephony`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html) framework.
But you will not be able to get any information about the incoming all like the number.

Also how do you plan on getting the location of the incoming call, since you can not deduct it from the number.