# iOS 7 or 8 - use custom vibrations

Tags: ios, iphone-vibrate

I want to trigger one of the custom vibrations that are in iOS 7 (you can see them when going into the native Contacts application and editing a contact) when my app gets a push notification. Is that possible? The best thing would be to specify the name of the vibration-alert in the push notification - but I don't think that's possible.

Another option would be to set a local notification with one of those custom vibrations (right after a push notification comes in). Is that possible?

Is there any other way for my app to use a vibration which is not the default one?
I know about this method `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);` What I'm looking for is to put in another argument to make the iPhone vibrate differently.

In the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966467/are-there-apis-for-custom-vibrations-in-ios)  there's an explanation of how to create a custom vibrate, but it uses some of Apple's internal methods, which to my understanding Apple does not approve.

UPDATE: Does anyone know if this is possible for iOS 8?

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this last week in iOS 8 too. Still there is no way to change the default vibration duration.

The function

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
```

produces a vibration that lasts 4 milliseconds with one millisecond of silence. I've tried to chain the same function call several times but there is always an interruption between two calls. I think there is no way to make a lengthy vibration that lasts more than 4 milliseconds :(

Comment: It's actually 0.4 seconds = 400ms

Comment: Can we increase the vibration time?