# How to make my iphone vibrate twice when I click on a button?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone-vibrate

I search to make vibrate twice my iphone when I click on a button (like a sms alert vibration)

With `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))`
I obtain just one normal vibration but I want two shorts :/.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966467/are-there-apis-for-custom-vibrations-in-ios

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>


AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(UInt32(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
```

This is the swift function...See [this](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-better-way-to-check-capabilities-of-ios-devices/) article for detailed description.

Comment: This isn't working for me, maybe Apple changed something or perhaps I'm doing something wrong? It's only giving me a single vibrate.

Answer (score 33):

**Update for iOS 10**

With iOS 10, there are a few new ways to do this with minimal code.

**Method 1 - [UIImpactFeedbackGenerator](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimpactfeedbackgenerator):**

```
let feedbackGenerator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy)
feedbackGenerator.impactOccurred()
```

**Method 2 - [UINotificationFeedbackGenerator](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinotificationfeedbackgenerator):**

```
let feedbackGenerator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
feedbackGenerator.notificationOccurred(.error)
```

**Method 3 - [UISelectionFeedbackGenerator](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiselectionfeedbackgenerator):**

```
let feedbackGenerator = UISelectionFeedbackGenerator()
feedbackGenerator.selectionChanged()
```

Comment: The UINotificationGenerator works only on devices that have a Taptic Engine. That's iPhone 7 and newer. I tried this code on my iPhone 6s, didn't work. I read a bit more about it and found out that it only works on devices that have a Taptic Engine and the System Haptics setting _must_ be enabled in System Settings, otherwise, it won't work.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I came up with:

```
import UIKit
import AudioToolbox

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var counter = 0
    var timer : NSTimer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func vibratePhone() {
        counter++
        switch counter {
        case 1, 2:
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
        default:
            timer?.invalidate()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func vibrate(sender: UIButton) {
        counter = 0
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.6, target: self, selector: "vibratePhone", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}
```

When you press the button, the timer starts and repeats at desired time interval. The NSTimer calls the vibratePhone(Void) function and from there I can control how many times the phone will vibrate. I used a switch in this case, but you could use a if else, too. Simply set a counter to count each time the function is called.

Comment: This works, but there's a lag prior to the first vibrate going off by about a second.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to vibrate only two times. You can just..

```swift
    func vibrate() {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithCompletion(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate) {
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
        }
    }
```

---

And vibrating multiple times can be possible by using recursion and `AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithCompletion`.

You can pass a count number to vibrate function like `vibrate(count: 10)`. Then it vibrates 10 times.

```swift
    func vibrate(count: Int) {
        if count == 0 {
            return
        }
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithCompletion(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate) { [weak self] in
            self?.vibrate(count: count - 1)
        }
    }
```

---

In case of using `UIFeedbackGenerator`, There is a great library [Haptica](https://github.com/efremidze/Haptica)

---

Hope it helps.

Comment: when u play audio, or webrtc call, only UIFeedbackGenerator work