# How to get status of system Haptics setting programmatically in ios?

Tags: ios10, setting, haptic-feedback

In my app, i want the user to enable or disable haptic feedback. When the haptic feedback of device is off, i will not allow the user to enable it. I want to know the status of haptic setting in the device and if its on/off.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if Haptic Engine (UIFeedbackGenerator) is supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41444274/how-to-check-if-haptic-engine-uifeedbackgenerator-is-supported)