# iOS haptic feedback at UISwitch crash

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, crash, haptic-feedback

There are some UISwitches at page (xamarin forms)
After keyboard opening there is a crash related to haptic feedback:

Terminating app due to an uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Exception raised while auto-deactivating for style 2: force deactivating with style TurnOn which is not active

It looks like iOS issue, and I have not found any workarounds.

Comment: Issue for iOS versions less than 12.

Comment: Tried creating component in custom renderer, so issue not in xamarin forms. Is it possible to disable haptic feedback of UISwitch to make it work without haptic vibration like at iPhone6 for instance?

Comment: Actually, Apple check the haptic feedback ability for you. Or you can use some private API to check the Api. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41444274/how-to-check-if-haptic-engine-uifeedbackgenerator-is-supported) post.