# Custom vibration in iOS 8 - Swift

Tags: swift, ios8, vibration

I'm writing a sprite kit-based app in swift and need to make a short haptic feedback using vibration

so first I imported AudioToolbox and used this

```
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
```

and it worked well but it vibrates for too long and there's no way to control this duration.

Then after some searching I read Kevin Cao's answer here:

[Are there APIs for custom vibrations in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966467/are-there-apis-for-custom-vibrations-in-ios)

but unfortunately AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration private function was only usable in iOS 6.

so is there any other possible way?

Answer (score 2):

You need AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration API.
But unfortunately it's private and you can not publish your app :(

Check [this blog post](http://corgitoergosum.net/2013/08/22/fun-with-private-apis/) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724980/making-the-iphone-vibrate)