# Custom Vibration in iOS8

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, audiotoolbox

To play vibration in iOS we use following :

`AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)`

But is it possible to play custom vibration patterns in iOS8? I know Prior to iOS7 we could use following private API :

```
 void AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration(SystemSoundID inSystemSoundID,id arg,NSDictionary* vibratePattern)
```

But is it possible to achieve in iOS8?

Comment: Same here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30268232/custom-vibration-in-ios-8-swift

Answer (score 0):

This private API is no longer available.

Answering your question: There is no way to achieve this anymore in iOS 8/9.