# Taptic in iOS 9

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9

Can you use the taptic engine in iOS 9 with iPhone 6s? WatchOS2 and OS X have the ability to use the haptic engine, so I assumed it would be in iOS 9 too, but I coudn't find any APIs for it.

Comment: "Taptic Engine API" was mentioned on the 07 Sept 16 Apple Keynote, so, no it's not on iOS9 but it seems to be coming soon.

Answer (score 50):

Yay, I had reverse engineered internal `UIKit` stuff and I found another (much simpler) way to actuate feedback via `TapticEngine`! We can just use `AudioToolbox` framework and several magic constants.

```
import AudioToolbox

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1519) // Actuate `Peek` feedback (weak boom)
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1520) // Actuate `Pop` feedback (strong boom)
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1521) // Actuate `Nope` feedback (series of three weak booms)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow this is amazing!! However does this count as a private API? They did include AudioServicesPlaySystemSound in the API reference but they didn't state what the numbers mean :O

Comment: This is philosophical question. In terms of App Store review process, any non-public API considers as private, but technically speaking almost any API usage can be obfuscated/hidden from Review Team. I think main issue here is appropriate or inappropriate usage of any particular API.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'm trying to incorporate this into my WWDC scholarship app and I don't wanna get rejected because of this. I just submitted the question to Apple and I'll update this if they have any comment on this.

Comment: My app (which is using this way to actuate taptic feedback) successfully passed App Review process. Yay! (Thank you, Apple!)

Comment: This is amazing. I'd be interested to know how you figured these existed though.

Comment: Those calls do not work on iOS 10 Beta 6 for me anymore.

Comment: Works on iOS 10.0.2 (:

Comment: @AvielGross That's awesome! Thank you for confirming.

Comment: From AudioServices.h: "This function will be deprecated in a future release. Use AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithCompletion instead."

Comment: @ValentinShergin do you have the 'magic' constants for UIImpactFeedbackGenerator?

Comment: These don't work on 10.2 and above from what I can see on my end

Comment: In case there's anyone else out there still targeting iOS 9 in 2021…  Word from Apple (on an [Apple Developer Forums post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/45628) that I think may be from @HenryNgan above) is: "It would not be appropriate to use undocumented arbitrary values in APIs, so I would recommend you *not* do that in your submission."

Answer (score 18):

**There is currently no public available API in iOS 9 and iOS 9.1.**

*Disclaimer: There is a way to interact with Taptic Engine directly, but there is a private method. You should not use it in App Store applications.*

However, if you are more into experimenting, then you can find that there is a new **private** class available in iOS 9: `_UITapticEngine`. You can find it's header [here](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/85fece6287a63e0e968edc71bc59ff07de29a470/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/_UITapticEngine.h). To get to it, there is a new property on `UIDevice` class, called `_tapticEngine`. See the full header for `UIDevice` [here](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/85fece6287a63e0e968edc71bc59ff07de29a470/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIDevice.h).  You can go ahead and import those headers, or just use `NSSelectorFromString` function and `performSelector:` method to get to the taptic engine:

```
id tapticEngine = [[UIDevice currentDevice] performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"_tapticEngine") withObject:nil];
[tapticEngine performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"actuateFeedback:") withObject:@(1001)]; // Peek
[tapticEngine performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"endUsingFeedback:") withObject:@(1002)]; // Pop
```

This will activate the taptic engine for specific gesture, although both Peek and Pop feel similar to me. If you specify any other constant, it will default to a vibration.

I have put together a quick test repo together on [GitHub](https://github.com/Legoless/TapticPlayground), that includes a Swift-compatible API to use the taptic engine:

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().tapticEngine().actuateFeedback(UITapticEngineFeedbackPeek)
```

**Use at your own risk!**

I've also written a bit longer [blog post](https://unifiedsense.com/development/using-taptic-engine-on-ios.html), explaining this.

Comment: Thanks for figuring out how to do this, and making a great blog post about it. I tried using this in a little app experiment of mine but found that when using the actuateFeedback method there was a limit to the rate of peak or pop feedback I could trigger, something like 5 or 6 per second. Do you know if there's any way to trigger these at a faster rate?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I do believe that would be a hardware limitation. Otherwise, I do not have an idea how to do this.

Comment: @kelin The link works, but it should be https, even though the browser should do a redirect. Can you try again?

Answer (score 10):

In iOS 10 there's a new API called UIFeedbackGenerator. See this [post](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-generate-haptic-feedback-with-uifeedbackgenerator?utm_campaign=This%2BWeek%2Bin%2BSwift&utm_medium=email&utm_source=This_Week_in_Swift_101) for more details. It only works on the iPhone 7 for now.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder what kind of limitation  there is that excludes the 6S(+) from using these APIs.

Comment: I don't know. Maybe it's the different kind of (physical) taptic engine, maybe it will be fixed in a future iOS update.

Comment: Don't provide links, the average link half-life on the Internet is THREE HOURS. StackOverflow is hopefully forever, but only if its content is *here*.

Answer (score 2):

**There doesn't seem to be a published API for iOS 9 currently.**

On OSX you need to use `NSHapticFeedbackManager`:

[NSHapticFeedbackManager Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSHapticFeedbackManager_class/)

and here is the API for `WatchOS2`:

[WKInterfaceDevice Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceDevice_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceDevice/playHaptic:)

By simply searching here you can see what I'm saying:

[Haptic search (iOS pre-release) - shows nothing](https://developer.apple.com/search/?q=haptic&platform=iOS%20Pre-release&type=Documentation)

[Haptic search (OSX pre-release) - shows NSHapticFeedbackManager](https://developer.apple.com/search/?q=haptic&platform=OS%20X%20Pre-release&type=Documentation)

Comment: The question is about iOS 9. You've posted links for OS X and WatchOS.