# Can I make an iPhone vibrate when in silent mode?

Tags: ios, push-notification, notifications, vibration, iphone-vibrate

Can I program my iOS app to vibrate an iPhone when the phone's "Vibrate on Silent" and "Vibrate on Ring" settings are turned off?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.  I just tested.  Do-not-disturb and silent mode do not disable vibration, but turning off  "Vibrate on Silent" and "Vibrate on Ring" do disable vibration entirely.

There is a private API documented [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966467/are-there-apis-for-custom-vibrations-in-ios) but generally Apple will not accept apps using an undocumented API, and it may not work anyway for your purpose.

For a general review on how to make an iPhone vibrate [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724980/making-the-iphone-vibrate)  is very thorough.

Comment: I've actually got the app's vibration working well when _not_ on silent mode using "AudioServicesPlaySystemSound". With my app's specific use-case, I'd like there to be a vibration on certain calls-to-action so people know exactly when to perform a task. Perhaps I can just check to see if vibration is enabled when the app launches, and if not, suggest they turn it on when using the app. I do not want to be using private APIs.

Answer (score 0):

In Settings, the "Vibrate on Silent" toggle and "Vibrate on Ring" toggle control whether the phone will vibrate or not when the phone is in those respective states (i.e., when the user flips the orange "Ring/Silent" switch on the left side of their phone).