# Vibrate indefinitely in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

How can I make an iPhone vibrate indefinitely? I know I can do this:

```
while true {
    AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
}
```

Is there any way to play the vibration for a certain number of seconds, or something with a similar result that is cleaner? Also, is there a way to make the vibration more intense?

Comment: I think, this answer can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966467/are-there-apis-for-custom-vibrations-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use **Timer**.

```
var timer: Timer?
var numberRepeat = 0
var maxNumberRepeat = 20

func startTimer() {
    //
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(self.timerHandler), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func stopTimer() {
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = nil
}

@objc func timerHandler() {
    if numberRepeat <= maxNumberRepeat {
        numberRepeat += 1
        vibrateDevice()
    } else {
        stopTimer()
    }
}

func vibrateDevice() {
    AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
}
```